# PHP + Youtube API - how to allow user to upload videos to my own channel?

Tags: php, api, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I am trying to build a web app that allows users to upload videos to my channel.

So I think I must go for [OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts), just as it says it there:

> Typically, an application uses a **service account** when the
>   application uses Google APIs to work with its **own data** rather than
>   a **user's data**.

So I have followed the steps to [create a service account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#creatinganaccount). But after completing the steps and have the key and id generated, I got an error below:

> An client error occurred: Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP
>   401: youtube.header, Unauthorized)

This is my entire code:

```
// Load 'Google/Client.php' and 'Google/Service/YouTube.php' with composer.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

$client_email = 'xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('xxx-74c6a50933e3.p12');
$scopes = array(
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner'
);

$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
     $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

$htmlBody = '';

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$htmlBody = '';

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try{
    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
    $videoPath = "/home/xxx/Desktop/Vids/small.mp4";

    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);

    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);


    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $status['snippet']['title'],
        $status['id']);

    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Uploaded</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what have I missed?

Comment: Could it be something as simple as an issue with the youtube channel settings? Possibly a setting to allow videos to be uploaded from a service account?

Comment: @TMartin `Possibly a setting to allow videos to be uploaded from a service account?` - how can I allow that from my channel?

Comment: I did some research and I'm not sure if what you're attempting is possible. Have you seen it successful elsewhere? See this:https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#service-accounts-do-not-work-with-the-youtube-api

Comment: Yes I did a web app in python with another developer many years ago. That web app allowed users to upload to the owner channel.

Comment: Do you still have access to that app's source code? Seeing a working version may help you bypass any restriction issues you are having with yours. I don't have a ton of experience with the youtube API so my knowledge is about limited to what I've told you so far. Good luck!

Comment: thanks. I have to dig for it but it was written in python.

Comment: Well hopefully the structure is similar enough alongside the API to see the difference in authentication.

Comment: Hope so! thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the answer from this [article](http://www.whitewareweb.com/php-youtube-video-upload-google-api-oauth-2-0-v3/).

Steps:

**Step 1.** Create a token.php (make sure set it to 777). Place the code example from Google - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video - with a little of this modification as follow:

Change:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
```

To:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);

  // @ref: http://www.whitewareweb.com/php-youtube-video-upload-google-api-oauth-2-0-v3/
  echo "Access Token: " . $_SESSION['token'];
}
```

**Step 2.** Run token.php on your browser. Grant the access. Then you get a json output below:

```
{
  "access_token": "xxxxt7YvjObwYx3DG4NRmfjiQ",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "xxxxq5hzQTUapZ7zyRIHP7X_G8",
  "created": 1466238624
}
```

Save it as token.txt

**Step 3.** Create upload.php with the same example code from Google - with the following modification:

**One.** Include token.txt file in the beginning of your upload.php:

```
$key = file_get_contents('token.txt');
```

Then pass `$key` into `new Google_Client()`:

```
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'xxxx.googleusercontent.com';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxx';

// Client init
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setAccessToken($key);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
```

**Two.** Add this code in the try catch section **before** `$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);`:

```
    /**
     * Check to see if our access token has expired. If so, get a new one and save it to file for future use.
     */
    if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $newToken = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
        $client->refreshToken($newToken->refresh_token);
        file_put_contents('token.txt', $client->getAccessToken());
    }
```

**Step 4**. Run upload.php that's it.

You can get the entire code from that article.

Answer (score -1):

I know  this sounds pretty weird, but I had the same issue the other day. I was trying different things... Try to change the YouTube category ID...

Try to change it to 1, took me hours of troubleshooting this to finally find that a lot of the categories do not work in the YouTube PHP SDK.

If that works, might want to make an API call to YouTube and get a list of all Category ID's, and try them all individually until you find the ones that do work... Documentation on how to do that is here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list

This is assuming that you have all of your OAuth tokens correct.

Comment: How do I get my OAuth tokens correctly? It asks me to authenticate each time when I try to upload from my web browser!

Comment: When you authenticate with OAuth, it should send back your initial token and a refresh token. You would need to use the refresh token each time the OAuth token expires and hit the Google Auth servers to get a new OAuth token. Take a look at the OAuth documentation linked here: [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

Comment: the thing is I don't want the user to authenticate when they want to upload from my website/ webapp. I just want to upload seemlessly without knowing about this bloody OAuth.

Comment: You will need to authenticate yourself using OAuth, then save the refresh token. Use the refresh token to authenticate with when a user uploads a video.

Comment: one question - how do i get the refresh token?

Comment: If I were to  paste that code in here, it would be a bit long and impose a security risk for the users of my applications. But here is a very detailed document from Google on how to do this: [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)

Comment: The absolute easiest way of doing this, using the Google Device access tokens... They have the same power as OAth, but they automatically get the refresh token. (It Still uses OAuth, but in a little bit of a different way.) [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#obtainingacode)